# Div fade in/out based on interaction with site

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, jquery-hover, interaction

I am trying to make a div that covers the site for x seconds and then disappears when the visitor is active on the page. The closest I have come:

```html
<div id="campaign">
</div>

<style>
/* campaign */

#campaign{
    display:block;
    background:url() center center no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    -moz-background-size: contain;
    -o-background-size: contain;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2 !important;
}

#campaign:hover{
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
</style>

<script>
$( "#campaign" ).click(function() {
  $( "#campaign" ).fadeOut( "fast", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
</script>
```

It now covers the page, and fades out when clicked.

I need it to fadeout when interacting on page and fade in when not interacting, meaning that if the user goes to another tab in their browser the #campaign will be made visible again when they go back to the page, but then disappears again when they interact with the site.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement idle timer which is complete library aveilable at https://github.com/thorst/jquery-idletimer but you can create your own logic based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```html
<script>
var timer;
$(document).mousemove(function() {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = 0;
    }

    $('#campaign:visible').fadeOut();
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#campaign').fadeIn()
    }, 3000)
})
</script>
```